# simple_token_authentication for Sign Up in ReactJS with Axios - Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am creating a simple Rails API that communicates with ReactJS.
I have tested the API endpoints using Postman and they work.

However, I am experiencing some issues when I submit my ReactJS form in order to register a new user.
I get the error:

> POST http://www.localhost:3000/api/v1/registration/reg 401 (Unauthorized)

I think the problem is that the authentication token is not submitted or created during my post request.

**ReactJS post request**

This is the ReactJS that handles the submit button of the form.

```
function handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post("http://www.localhost:3000/api/v1/registration/reg")
        .then(res => {console.log(res)})
        .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})

}
```

If I try with `Postman` or in `Rails Console`, I am able to create a new user.
For example, in postman I just did:
1) POST `localhost:3000/api/v1/registration/reg`
2) Create a random user:
3)

```
{
    "email": "waffle@gmail.com",
    "password": "12345678"
}
```

4) I get back:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "email": "waffle@gmail.com",
    "created_at": "2019-12-28T22:59:59.454Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-28T22:59:59.454Z",
    "authentication_token": "SzqjkJd5ocbVh1MziZZA"
}
```

This does not occur with ReactJS, I get back:

> POST http://www.localhost:3000/api/v1/registration/reg 401 (Unauthorized)

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach your data and authorization token.

```
var user={
       "email": "waffle@gmail.com",
      "password": "12345678"
         }
var config = {
    headers: {'Authorization': "bearer " + token}
};

axios.post('http://www.localhost:3000/api/v1/registration/reg/user', 
  user,
  config
    )
    .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

if you are using Http basic authentication just add

```
auth: {
    username: '....',
    password: '...'
}
```

insted of config.

Comment: Thanks. What I do not get is how I can pass the `key` and `token`. They exists in the backend, how do I pass them in the front? Do I have to create a first API passing them to the front, and the populate `key` and `token`?

Comment: Do I have to create a first API passing them to the front? Yes, you should

Comment: and  Key, value means your data, in your case ,`{
       "email": "waffle@gmail.com",
      "password": "12345678"
         }`

Answer (score 0):

Since the user doesn't exist yet, there is no token right?
So you want to use skip the authorization before the create function of a user. So when you go to register a new user, you don't need to send a token to have access to that route.

```
class UsersController <ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authenticate_user_from_token!, :only => [ :create]
  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    render json: @user
  end
```

Now that user is created, you can hit the login route, and you'll receive the token if your logon is successful, here is my sessions controller for my login route

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user_from_token!

  # POST /login
  def create
    @user = User.find_for_database_authentication( email: params[:user][:email])
    return invalid_login_attempt unless @user

    if @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
      sign_in :user, @user
      render json: @user, serializer: SessionSerializer, root: nil
    else
      invalid_login_attempt
    end
  end

  private

  def invalid_login_attempt
    warden.custom_failure!
    render json: {error: t('sessions_controller.invalid_login_attempt')}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

end
```

it's your job on the front end to maintain that token, that you received from the login route. and apply it to the rest of your fetch requests through the headers authorization argument

`headers: {'Authorization': "bearer " + token}`